# How can I overload simple Delphi Functions of Integers?

Tags: delphi, types, overloading

Using Delphi 7, I have several functions that take a single integer parameter.  These functions operate on a Text string belonging to the object.  The only parameter is either a character index in the Text, or a word index.  For example, to retrieve the next word of Text after word i or after the character Text[loc] I want to have:

```
function NextWord(i:Integer): String; overload;
function NextWord(loc:Integer): String; overload;
```

Obviously, this is ambiguous.  Delphi Help says "Overloaded routines must be distinguished by the number of parameters they take or the types of their parameters."  So I defined two types:

```
type WordIndex = Integer;
type CharIndex = Integer;
...
function NextWord(i:WordIndex): String; overload;
function NextWord(i:CharIndex): String; overload;
```

But this doesn't work, as these are just aliases for Integer.

Delphi Help on types distinguishes 'type identity', 'type compatibility', and 'assignment-compatibility', and then says nothing about how to use the distinction.  But it does say to repeat the word 'type' to create new type not identical to Integer:

```
type WordIndex = type Integer;    //really, a new type
type CharIndex = type Integer;
...
function NextWord(i:WordIndex): String; overload;
function NextWord(i:CharIndex): String; overload;
...
var WordNumber: WordIndex;      //variable of new type
...
  WordStr := NextWord(WordNumber);  //call overloaded function
```

To my surprise, this doesn't work either.  The compiler recognizes WordIndex as a separate type, and compiles the overloaded functions, but where called it claims the overload is ambiguous. I also tried changing the function parameters to VAR (because "For var parameters, types of formal and actual must be identical."), but that didn't help.

Hitting the Web I read that the compiler disambiguates overloaded functions based first on the number of parameters, and second on their size.  I suppose I could make WordIndex a DWord instead of Integer, but I don't want it to be 16 bits, and I'm using -1 to mean 'invalid word number'.

Finally, I found this in the Help for 'Overloading procedures and functions':  "You can pass to an overloaded routine parameters that are not identical in type with those in any of the routine's declarations, but that are assignment-compatible with the parameters in more than one declaration. ... In these cases, when it is possible to do so without ambiguity, the compiler invokes the routine whose parameters are of the type with the smallest range that accommodates the actual parameters in the call."

So I tried this, which works:

```
type WordIndex = -1..High(Integer);
type CharIndex =  Integer;
function NextWord(i:WordIndex): String; overload;
function NextWord(i:CharIndex): String; overload;
...
var WordNumber: WordIndex;
    loc: CharIndex;
...
  WordStr := NextWord(WordNumber);
  (or)
  WordStr := NextWord(loc);
```

This compiles without warnings or errors, and does in fact call the correct function for each parameter type.  Also SizeOf(WordIndex) = SizeOf(CharIndex) = 4.  I.E. they're both Integers.

My question is, is this how I'm **supposed** to do it?  And if so, how was I supposed to know that?  Are there any examples like that in the Help or in the Source?

Bonus question: I checked, and making type WordIndex a Range creates no code/runtime overhead in the call or in the functions.  But might it elsewhere in the code?  Will Delphi be testing WordNumber for a Range Error anywhere it wouldn't be testing an Integer? (I'm pretty sure the answer is 'No'.)

Comment: the functions do different things, why do you want to overload them, instead of taking different function names ?

Comment: No, that is not how you are suppost to do it. You are supposed to give the functions different names.

Comment: The functions do the same thing (returning the next word) using different information.  I maintain both the current word and character.  As I analyze the text, some operations involve stepping by words, other by characters.  At the end of the operation my current position is whichever index the operation used.  And I want to move to the beginning of the next word.

Comment: "give the functions different names"  That's the problem: They already *have* different names -- 18 of them.  Names like NextWordFromIndex() and NextWordFromLocation(), but also NextIndexFromLocation, and PreviousLocationFromIndex.  I'm trying to simplify it and make it more readable.

Comment: The names you have sound good. Much better than your proposed solution.

Comment: I would move the functions into a class that maintains state information, then have only one `NextWord()` method that uses the state information to decide what to do.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's not obvious to me that there should be persistent state here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trying to use overloading here just leads to pain and suffering. Just imagine what happens when you want to use an integer literal? Or imagine you want to pass NextWord an index that is an expression, e.g. a+b. Or you pass the return value of a function. Are you going to have functions that return the various dedicated types that you propose to define? And think about any human that has to read the code. How would they be expected to determine which overload is being called?

You can avoid all the pain by giving your functions different names. Overloading is appropriate when you have multiple functions that take parameters with different types. That is not the case here. Your functions take parameters with the same type. And so your functions need different names.

Another way to organise it would be to have a single function, but to pass more to the function. Pass the index, and an enumerated type which describes how to interpret that index. You could combine those two values into a record.

Comment: +1. In addition, how is the next developer who tries to read the code supposed to know what you intended with each use of the poorly named functions? It's much easier to just type a few more characters and use something like `NextWordFromCharIndex` and `NextWordFromWordIndex` or something. The extra typing is reduced by code completion, and also by the clearer intent of the code.

Comment: That's what I have now.  Let me tell you, it's *not* readable or easy to maintain.  I take it you would have no problem overloading if CharIndex were a Real?  Yes, I plan to have functions that return the two dedicated types.  Passing an expression (a+b) makes no sense in this context.  One never needs the word at i+5j.  I don't even want to simply increment the indexes.  Using one of my 'Next' functions will increment it and handle edge case.  Why should a human reading the code need to determine which overload is called?  Do you worry if Inc(i) called Inc64 or not?

Comment: Sorry if the above sounds combative.  It's merely the short length of these comments in which to address all your points.  The best one, I think, is about checking what's passed.  If I make the function parameters VAR, then Delphi should strictly enforce the caller using WordIndex or CharIndex, and not allow a simple Integer.  And I *am* open to the possibility that this is a bad idea -- but I'm not convinced of it.

Comment: @Ken, what poorly named functions? NextWord() accepts a location as either a WordIndex or a CharIndex, and returns the next word as a string. How is the intention unclear? How is this different from Inc() which accepts either an Integer or an Int64? Or VectorLength() that accepts either Polar or Cartesian coordinates?  Consider that a Word array index and the index of a char in a string really **are** different types. They just both happen to fit in 32-bit integers. If I restricted WordIndex to 16 bits, would you then be happy with overloaded functions? If not, then what's really the problem?

Comment: @Guy: David and I both explained what the problem is - the reason you're fighting with the compiler is because you're doing something wrong. The poorly named functions are the two that are named poorly, which I clearly mentioned in my comment. If the compiler can't figure out what you intend, you need to rethink what you're doing. Trust me - it's smarter about Delphi code than we are, and if it's telling you you're doing something that doesn't make sense, you should listen. :-)

Comment: It is completely different from Inc. The Inc overloads do the same operation to different typed data. Your proposal does different things to same typed data. Because the functions perform different tasks they need different names.

Comment: @David, You're wrong.  Inc overloads do not perform the same operation.  One performs a 32-bit add, another a 64-bit add.  The entire point of overloading is to return the same **logical** result for different types while hiding the implementation.  Imagine I have a type Vector(X:Real,Y:Real) or Vector(Length:Real,Angle:Real).  It makes perfect sense to overload VectorAdditon on these Vectors.   Yet the primitive types of all the parameters are Real -- it is their meaning which differs.  However, since the Range of Angle is -360.0..360.0 degrees, Delphi will allow the overload.

Comment: @Ken, I find your argument **totally persuasive**.  Allow me to rephrase it slightly:  "The compiler knows better than you or I.  If it allows (indeed documents) this behavior then it's OK.  If not, don't do it."  Are we in agreement? :-)

Comment: If you think that 32 bit add and 64 bit are different operations then there's really no point in us continuing this discussion. Our views are clearly never to line up.

Comment: @Guy: Partially. :-) Change "if it allows this behavior then it's OK, unless you have to jump through hoops or use ugly typecasting or other other kludges to make it happy, in which case don't do it." and we're in agreement. (I think you're in the second half of that statement. ;-)

Comment: I've decided David was right in his very first paragraph.  It's irrelevant that I don't intend to pass NextWord an expression if I can't make Delphi **enforce** that behavior.  I thought that passing the parameter as VAR would enforce strict formal type agreement.  But for reasons currently unclear to me, that is not the case.  I intend to post a longer explanation at a later date.

Answer (score 1):

If you run into this type of problem, use refactoring to separate the different behavior. For example, you could split the word extraction by location and char index, you could introduce two new classes:

The call would be:

```
MyClass.Location.NextWord(SomeIndex);
MyClass.Character.NextWord(SomeIndex);
```

Another approach could be to provide the method using a second parameter:

```
MyClass.NextWord(SomeWordIndex, wmiByWordLocation);
MyClass.NextWord(SomeCharIndex, wmiByCharLocation);
```

However, I would recommend refactorization.

Comment: I have a better idea.  I will create an abstract data type that I will call a Location.  Location might be an object, interface, or record.  You are not allowed to peek inside. :-)  Location will provide a means to move forward and back by character or word, access to both the character and word at Location, and a peek at the NextChar or NextWord.  The beauty of OOP is truly blinding!  Now I must implement my ADT.  Hmmmm.  I'll need a function to return the NextWord, whether Location is at the beginning of a word, or at some other char.  (Continued at the top of S.O. Q#13435812) :-)

Comment: Yes, that is clean as well. But it would be more of a TLocationMover, wouldn't it? A location itself would not be interested how to move, it is interested where it is located. Anyway, you are going into the right direction.